# How can I use RadioButton to turn visible others RadioButtons?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, radio-button, visible

I've been trying to use a RadioButton to turn visible another. I am new to this enviroment and this is my first Windows Phone app. 
My code:

```
 private void rb1_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        RadioButton rb1 = new System.Windows.Controls.RadioButton();

        if (rb1.IsChecked == true)
        {
            this.rb2.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
        else if (rb1.IsChecked == false)
        {
           this.rb2.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
```

Isnt working well. I am trying to do this with Windows Phone Emulator. I already found something called autopostback, is there a similar property to Windows Phone too?

If I want to turn it dynamic?

Comment: Since the UI guideline for a radio button is for only one to be active at a time, what would be the point of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that is isn't working is because you instantiate a new radio button called rb1.  If there is already an rb1, then you can try this:

Try:

```
private void rb1_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (rb1.IsChecked == true)
        {
            this.rb2.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
        else if (rb1.IsChecked == false)
        {
           this.rb2.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean?  Can you post your XAML and explain your end goal?

Comment: Hi @jle I'm sorry about my late answer, I did a trip. There were another errors at my code that were causing it. Thank you very much about your spent time!

Answer (score 0):

You can delete

```
RadioButton rb1 = new System.Windows.Controls.RadioButton();
```

because you create instance every time that you click

Comment: If I want to turn it dynamic? For example: I have two rbuttons and one show a groupname and another show other groupname?

Comment: Please, explain it better! ;D